# Force mobile implementation for Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I've noticed that a tab on a particular Google Sheet we've developed 'runs' a lot faster (about 70-80 times faster) on a mobile than on a desktop - ie it calculates and returns its results faster. The one tab in particular that uses a query to filter a master database. I surmise that this is because there's a very reduced 'view' window on a mobile and Google Apps cleverly off loads the heavy lifting to its servers when it sees a mobile opening the sheet.

My question is, and this is speculation, can I use a script to force a particular Google Sheet to always report to the Google Servers that it's running on a mobile?

Comment: I think you cannot limit the Google Apps Script on mobile only. [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview) is a scripting language based on JavaScript that lets you do new and cool things with Google Apps like Docs, Sheets, and Forms. It is also a server side technology i.e instead of running client side like typical javascript, it runs on the Google Cloud. A language to develop web apps that can automate task across Google products and third party services. Just check the Apps Script link to know the things that you can do with it.

Comment: Thanks KENdi. I didn't make it particularly clear I see. It wasn't the running of the script that I was particularly concerned about, just the potential ability (in any form) to force the Google Cloud servers to take some of the heavy lifting away from the client machine, be that a mobile, desktop or whatever.